# Option not removing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have an issue with my code on IE. Basically it won't remove the option on IE. It works fine on chrome.

```
function removeYrEndAndPettyCashCat() {
for (var i = 0; i < catsToRemove.length; i++) {
    $('option[value = "' + String(catsToRemove[i].ID) + '"]').remove();
}
}
```

I have checked a few posts on this site and they say that .remove should work and it does in the console. However when I am trying to remove upon clicking on the dropdown the first time the dropdown appears it has the option still there. If I close the dropdown and open it again the option is now gone. This is only happening in IE. Has anyone come across this and if so could you suggest a fix?

Comment: try submitting a Fiddle or executable snippet please

Comment: I think it is better you provide more code. Maybe your mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: Not sure if a remove method on the option element is standard; try using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove instead

Answer (score 1):

- Which IE browser are you using
- Are you sure you execute your code on document ready or when the select is filled/created.

I just worked on a sample and it seems to work in IE11.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="test"] option').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() === "remove"){
    $(this).remove();
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id='test' name="test">
   <option value="remove">Remove1</option>
   <option value="remove">Remove2</option>
   <option value="keep">Remove3</option>
   <option value="remove">Remove4</option>
   <option value="keep">Remove5</option>
   <option value="keep">Remove6</option>
   <option value="remove">Remove7</option>
   <option value="remove">Remove8</option>
   <option value="remove">Remove9</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by adding a timeout. Basically IE is executing the javascript before the dropdown is being loaded dynamically. This is really annoying as Chrome doesn't have this issue.